# Vagrant chef-solo not finding cookbook file that exists

Tags: git, vagrant, chef-infra

I am running the following receipt through vagrant and chef-solo, whose purpose is to clone a GIT repository:

```
# Recipe that includes all dependencies
include_recipe "sesame::packages"
include_recipe "sesame::git_key"

# Create folders
directory node['sesame']['sourcecode_dir'] do
    owner node['sesame']['user']
    group node['sesame']['group']
    mode "0750"
    action :create
end

directory node['sesame']['temp_dir'] do
    owner node['sesame']['user']
    group node['sesame']['group']
    mode "0750"
    action :create
end

# Creating the SSH wrapper for git
cookbook_file "#{node['sesame']['temp_dir']}/git_ssh_wrapper.sh" do
    source "git_ssh_wrapper.sh"
    owner node["sesame"]["user"]
    group node["sesame"]["group"]
    mode "0755"
end

# Clone the git repo
git node['sesame']['sourcecode_dir'] do
    user node['sesame']['user']
    group node['sesame']['group']
    ssh_wrapper "#{node['sesame']['temp_dir']}/git_ssh_wrapper.sh"
    repository node['sesame']['git_repo']
    reference "master"
    action :sync
    timeout 9999
end
```

The error I get when executing the receipt is:

```
STDERR: error: cannot run /home/vagrant/tmp/git_ssh_wrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

This file corresponds to the file that should be created in the cookbook-file resource.

What puzzles me is that if I ssh to the machine, the `git_ssh_wrapper.sh` file is there, so I cannot understand why chef complains that it cannot find it.

In case it matters, I run Vagrant from a Windows host, but the machine where chef is running is an Ubuntu precise64.

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards

Daniel

Comment: When you login to the box via `kitchen login`, is `/home/vagrant/tmp/git_ssh_wrapper.sh` an actual path/to/that/thing.sh ?

Comment: I login using `vagrant ssh box` and `git_ssh_wrapper.sh` is there. What I noted is that this recipe is the first one in a run-list where other recipes have a similar structure and try to create the same file to clone other git repos. When I execute `vagrant up` I see some `WARN` messages regarding this file that seem to be related with the other recipes in the run-list (although those have not executed yet). I thought if adding a check for the existence of the file before creating it might help?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem. The file `git_ssh_wrapper.sh` was there, but was not executing properly. The reason is that I had cloned the git repository hosting the recipes to a Windows host, and in the process a DOS end of line character had been inserted in the file, which made it fail once chef would try to execute it.

I had to add the following configuration line to my Git installation to clone the repository without inserting DOS end of lines:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```